# Convert Lua or JSON-table to XML in pure Lua

Tags: json, xml, lua, converters

I'm looking for a converter that converts a JSON-table to xml. The problem is, is that I cannot use libraries such LUAXML, because I use an flashbased computer with Lua. The converter must be written in pure Lua. Please help?

Comment: I think it quite offtop on SO. I think build xml from lua table is quie simple. To decode JSON you can try `dkjson` library. As I know it is pure Lua (single Lua file) and have optional deps from lpeg.

Comment: Would also be nice to know how you want to format the XML tags. You can use stuff as ```<String KEY>VALUE</KEY>``` or just ```<KEY>VALUE>/KEY>```. Could you specify for what you're planning to use this _(platform etc)_? As @moteus said: There are XML libraries out there written in pure Lua. The same for JSON, e.g. https://github.com/cloudkick/Agent-Lua-Plugins/blob/master/Json.lua   _(I also always cringe when people say LUA instead of Lua)_

Comment: What have you written so far, and why isn't it working? If you haven't written any code so far, why not?